# Angular BehaviorSubject pass value to a component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, behaviorsubject

I am in need of some help and assistance with BehaviorSubject in Angular. I have an app that has a footer component in which I would like to display the number of products in cart.

I get the amount of products in cart and other cart data over API.
Here is how the cart data from API looks like:

**shopping-cart.ts**

```
export interface ShoppingCart {
  total_products: number;
  totals: number;
  notes: string;
  shipping_method: string;
}
```

Here is the API call to get all the cart data:
**cart.service.ts**

```
  getCart() {
    return from(Preferences.get({key: 'TOKEN_KEY'})).pipe(
      switchMap(token => {
        const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token.value}`);
        return this.httpClient.get<ShoppingCart>(`${environment.apiUrl}cart`, {headers, observe: 'response'});
      }),
      catchError(err => {
        console.log(err.status);
        if (err.status === 400) {
          console.log(err.error.message);
        }
        if (err.status === 401) {
          this.authService.logout();
          this.router.navigateByUrl('/login', {replaceUrl: true});
        }
        return EMPTY;
      }),
    );
  }
```

Here is the code in **cart.page.ts** where I am getting the cart data:

```
  getCart() {
    this.getCartSubscription = this.cartService.getCart().subscribe(
      (data: any) => {
        const productsData = data.body.products;
        const totalProducts = data.body.total_products;
        const totalCartPrice = data.body.totals;
        this.products = productsData.map(products => products);
        this.totalProducts = totalProducts;
        this.totalCartPrice = totalCartPrice;
        console.log('Products in cart:', data.body);
      },
      error => {
        console.log('Error', error);
      });
  }
```

Here is how I was attempting to send data to my footer component:
**in the cart.service.ts file I have added this code:**

```
  shopingCartData: ShoppingCart;

  private cartQtySource = new BehaviorSubject(this.shopingCartData);
  currentValue = this.shopingCartData.total_products;

  constructor(
    ...some other code...
  ) { }

  getCartQty(qty: number) {
    this.cartQtySource.next(qty);
  }
```

How do I send the data of number of products in the cart from cart page to the footer component so I always get the current ammount?

Comment: `BehaviorSubject` needs an `initial value`, what is `this.shopingCartData`? you can set the value, like you have done `this.cartQtySource.next(qty);` and you get the value `this.cartQtySource.value` if you just want the value, or else you can make an observable from this `subject` using `toObservable` and `subscrible` to it if you want some operation to be triggered based on it. you can create it in a reusable `service` from where you can import and use in different components. It would be better if you can create a stackblitz or code sandbox, so that it's easier to help.

Comment: @HarshitT this.shopingCartData is the ShopingCart (shoping-cart.ts file

Comment: @I am verry new to angular and dont really understand your answer :) I will try to create a StackBlits

Comment: that would be helpful.

Comment: @HarshitT here is the StackBlitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gz9nrc?file=tsconfig.json

Comment: I’ve added the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `cart.service.ts`

you cannot do

```
  private cartQtySource = new BehaviorSubject(this.shopingCartData);
  currentValue = this.shopingCartData.total_products;
```

because `shopingCartData` has only been declared and has no data, and it will throw an error.

instead you can do:

```
private cartQtySource = new BehaviorSubject(0);
cartQtySource$ = this.cartQtySource.asObservable();
```

You already have `getCartQty()` in place, so you can use it directly in `cart.page.ts` like below:

```
getCart() {
    this.getCartSubscription = this.cartService.getCart().subscribe(
      (data: any) => {
        const productsData = data.body.products;
        const totalProducts = data.body.total_products;
        const totalCartPrice = data.body.totals;
        this.products = productsData.map(products => products);
        this.totalProducts = totalProducts;
        this.totalCartPrice = totalCartPrice;
        this.cartService.getCartQty(totalProducts);
        console.log('Products in cart:', data.body);
      },
      error => {
        console.log('Error', error);
      });
  }
```

Also, `getCartSubscription` has been made on `httpClient` observable, so you don't have to unsubscribe to it manually, angular will handle it.

Lastly, you just need to get these values in your `footer.component.ts`, which you can do like this:

```
export class FooterComponent implements OnInit {
  private getCartSubscription: Subscription;
  constructor(private cartService: CartService) {}
  totalProducts = 0;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.cartService.cartQtySource$.subscribe((tp: number) => {
      this.totalProducts = tp
      console.log('Numbner of products: ', this.totalProducts);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey altho this works but there are also other pages that have the option to add items to cart.. how do I make this function that updates the number of items in cart available to other components?

Comment: also on app refresh until i go to the cart the number of items in cart is shown as 0... after i go to cart page only then it updates to the real value

Comment: to change the number of items you can use `this.cartService.getCartQty('whatever the quantity is');` wherever you are changing the the cart items.

Comment: since your api is getting called in the cart page, until you load that component, it will it as 0. you can either subscribe to the `this.cartService.getCart()` in your footer component as well, and get the data there, or, you can create another `BehaviorSubject` and call the api in `parent of cart and footer` and set it's value, and use that subject in cart and footer like I showed above.

Comment: Hey, thank you very much for this, I have successfully implemented the functionality how I wanted it and learned something :)

Answer (score 1):

Just make the current value as observable so that in footer component you can subscribe to the changes made to currentValue

cart.service.ts

```
shopingCartData: ShoppingCart;

  private cartQtySource = new BehaviorSubject(this.shopingCartData);
  // currentValue = this.shopingCartData.total_products; <-- Change this

  currentValue = this.cartQtySource.asObservable(); // <-- to this

  constructor(
    ...some other code...
  ) { }

  getCartQty(qty: number) {
    this.cartQtySource.next(qty);
  }
```

then on footer component add the ngOnInit function and suscribe to the current value observable this should resolve your issue

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.cartService.currentValue.subscribe(
      (qty: number) => {
        this.cartQty = qty;
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: This return a bunch of errors

Comment: could you post the error ?